# Mouse Scroll Button Shortcut in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, mouseevent

Hi I'm working on eclipse 4.19 (Maven Java Projects)

You know that if the mouse cursor was on the method and then click F3 , you will open the method declaration.

My question is , How to open the method declaration when I click on the mouse scroll button ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The scroll button will not navigate to the method declaration but you could use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Mouse Click

Comment: any mouse click is not doable on binding field